# HLSL preprocessor in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, hlsl

I am working over DirectX shaders and C++ code in Visual Studio 2015 and I want to make just one code, so I started to play with macros, because  I consider it as effective way how to unified the code.

HLSL preprocessor in visual studio is little bit different than C++ preprocessor, e.g. it does not support variadic macros; on the other hand basic work is the same (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943993(v=vs.85).aspx)).

My problem is that when I use following code:

```
STATIC_TRAITS_DECLARATION SimpleVertexDefinition(PARSER_MEMORY, CONTEXT_MEMORY)
```

Where **all the terms** (*SimpleVertexDefinitions, STATIC_TRAITS_DECLARATION, CONTEXT_MEMORY, PARSER_MEMORY*) **are macros**, everything works fine. But when I try to define it by following macro

```
#define DECLARE_VERTEX_SHADER_INPUT(type) STATIC_TRAITS_DECLARATION type##Definition(PARSER_MEMORY, CONTEXT_MEMORY)

DECLARE_VERTEX_SHADER_INPUT(SimpleVertex)
```

I get

```
Error   X1516   not enough actual parameters for macro 'SimpleVertexDefinition' 
Error   X3000   unrecognized identifier 'SimpleVertexDefinition'
```

By the way

- C++ preprocessor has no problem to compile it
- Macro concatenation works fine in other hlsl codes.

I would be glad if somebody can explain me what is wrong, because I believe that my macros are written according [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943993(v=vs.85).aspx)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is probably in wrong implementation of preprocessor in **fxc.exe** (effect compiler tool).

Possible solution is to configure Visual Studio manually to

- preprocess file with c++ compiler `cl.exe file /P [other option] /FipreprocessedFile`
- and then compile it with effect compiler tool `fxc.exe preprocessedFile [options]`

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6ccd269-8ef4-4b80-b575-da58894a71ee/hlsl-preprocessor-in-visual-studio-2015?forum=vclanguage

Comment: Could somebody confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Well it isn't a bug in the Microsoft's HLSL implementation. Actually the HLSL processor works differently(which is a pity). See the link below for more details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

As a workaround you could use a preprocessing library(I use fcpp, it works OK) to preprocess the code before passing it to the HLSL compiler.

Comment: It is bug (as confirmed on MSDN) and yeah this preprocessor works differently than standard c++ preprocessor. Described example is not out of specification of HLSL preprocessor, even so it fails, thus it could be considered as bug...